# iOS Venmo SDK Send Payment Issue: Invalid recipient (Please enter a valid phone, email, username, or Venmo user ID)

Tags: ios, sdk, payment, send, venmo

I integrated Venmo SDK and I'm facing an issue while sending payment. 
I have configured everything correctly.
I click Pay via Venmo button -> App redirects -> Approve -> Comes back to Send Payment Screen. 
When I click Send payment I get an error "Invalid recipient (Please enter a valid phone, email, username, or Venmo user ID)"

I have checked the "sendPaymentTo" field which has the right phone number, correct amount and even a Note field.

```
(IBAction)sendAction:(id)sender {

    void(^handler)(VENTransaction *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(VENTransaction *transaction, BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:error.localizedDescription
                                                                message:error.localizedRecoverySuggestion
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            alertView.tapBlock = ^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
                [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];
            };
            [alertView show];
        }
        else {
            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(paymentSuccesfull:)]) {
                [self.delegate paymentSuccesfull:transaction.transactionID];
            }
            [[Venmo sharedInstance] logout];
        }
    };

    [[Venmo sharedInstance] sendPaymentTo:self.phoneNumber
                                   amount:self.amountTextField.text.floatValue*100
                                     note:self.noteTextField.text
                        completionHandler:handler];
}
```

Comment: What version of the Venmo app and Venmo SDK are you using?

Comment: Also, what format is your phone number in?

Comment: I'm using Venmo SDK 1.0.0 and phone number format is "+1415XXX1234".

Comment: I need more information on how you get `self.phoneNumber`

Comment: And how are you sure that the phone number is valid?

Comment: Try updating your SDK to 1.0.2. If you are using cocoapods, run `pod update`

Comment: I found the issue, It was related to Phone number format not the phone number itself.

I formated the phone number to "+1(415)XXX-XXXX" for display purposes and Venmo SDK doesn't recognise this format. It has to be "+1415XXXYYYY".

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug in the error messaging from the SDK. The real issue I believe is that you're sending an invalid amount (such as .01, the amount field is actually in cents already). I opened an issue here: https://github.com/venmo/venmo-ios-sdk/issues/47

Comment: I have sent $0.01 via my app(using VenmoSDK) however minimum amount you send via Venmo app itself is $1.0 Fixing the phone number format resolved the issue.

Comment: I am getting the same error and even formatting the number is not solving it. This is happening in android for me.